# How to work with three point lighting system?

Tags: light

I try to use three point lighting system but I don't know how to put the free light -90 opposite from the first plane.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to set the *pivot center type* to *3D Cursor*, place the cursor wherever you like, select a plane, duplicate it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>) along the Z axis by 90 degress (you may type a rotation value using your numerical keyboard).
[image]

The other method is using a ***Mirror Modifier***. Choose the *axis* you want your plane to mirror and input the name of your illuminated object in a window under *Mirror Object:*. Then apply the modifier.
[image]

Go to *Edit Mode*, select all mirrored meshes (<kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>P</kbd>*-->Separate-->By Loose Parts* to make them separate objects. Now select one of them, snap the cursor to the center of it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>*-->Cursor to Selected*). Enter the *Object Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>*-->Origin to 3D Cursor* to place the origin point within. Repeat the same process with other planes.
[image]

You may now adjust the transformations of the planes changing the *transformation orientation type* to ***Normal*** (tap <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> twice to make it work).
[image]